# Problems with inserting urls including Turkish characters

Tags: bibtex, characters, turkish

I am trying to include this url link:

```
http://wiki.ubuntu-tr.net/index.php?title=Linux_dağıtımları_kılavuzu
```

into the bibliography of my LaTeX report. 'dağıtımları_kılavuzu' is causing a display problem on my latex file. My code is the following:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[condensed,math]{iwona}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[turkish,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\bibliographystyle{plainyr}%Sorts by year.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bbding} %for tick and cross symbols
\usepackage[pdftex,pagebackref=true,linktocpage=false,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=red,anchorcolor=green,breaklinks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,pdfpagelabels,hyperindex=true,bookmarks,hyperfigures,bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}
\title{\color{red}An overview of current operating systems}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents

\cite{ldk}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References} % changes default name Bibliography to References
\bibliography{References/references} % References file

\end{document}
```

the reference is defined in the bibtex file as:

```
@UNPUBLISHED{ldk,author="{Ubuntu Community}",title="{Linux da\u{g}{\i}t{\i}mlar{\i} k{\i}lavuzu}",note={URL: \url{http://wiki.ubuntu-tr.net/index.php?title=Linux_dağıtımları_kılavuzu}},month={Accessed: 6 October},year={2014}}
```

the output is

[image]

so what should be the most efficient way to solve this issue?

Comment: imo (uninformed opinion, really), this is where you need to give up 8-bit tex and go to xetex (or luatex, if you're adventurous enough).  the uk faq has nothing about “multilingual” bibliographies, and it's one of the things on my current list ... trouble is, i've essentially no ‘definitive’-sounding inputs to craft a faq answer from; can anyone offer anything?

Comment: The essential problem seems to be `\url{\i}`.  Not sure how to solve that.

Comment: a small correction: the url in the bib is defined as: \url{http://wiki.ubuntu-tr.net/index.php?title=Linux_da\u{g}{\i}t{\i}mlar{\i}_k{\i}lavuzu}

Comment: Did you try adding `\usepackage{lmodern}`? The problem might come from the default `Computer Modern`. `Latin Modern` is very close to the default but is T1 encoded.

Comment: I have just tried using the package lmodern. It is ineffective unfortunately.

Comment: by the way, yes, ğ is outputted correctly. The only problem is printing ı properly.

Comment: After some testing I can confirm that the problem is caused by `hyperref`'s implementation of `\url`. If you just type the URL in `\texttt` (you have to do `$\_$` for the underscores) all the characters print.

Comment: Part of the problem may be that URIs actually do not contain Unicode characters; they are translated into "percent encoding": see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386262/should-i-use-accented-characters-in-urls and http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/.

Comment: Do the above comments mean that it is not possible to use url, hyperref and Turkish characters all together?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a bug in `hyperref`, as `ğ` prints correctly.

A horrible kludge to solve it is to use

```
@UNPUBLISHED{ldk,
  author={{Ubuntu Community}},
  title={Linux da\u{g}{\i}t{\i}mlar{\i} k{\i}lavuzu},
  note={URL: \url{http://wiki.ubuntu-tr.net/index.php?title=Linux_da%C4%9F%C4%B1t%C4%B1mlar%C4%B1_k%C4%B1lavuzu}},
  month={Accessed: 6 October},
  year={2014}
}
```

The encoding can be obtained various converters. The benefit is that the link is guaranteed to point to the correct location.

[image]